# Getting zeros on Cortex-A9 PMU counters

Tags: android, linux, kernel, cortex-a

not sure if this the right place to ask but i really need help.

I am attempting to gather some data on Galaxy Nexus i9250 Android v4.3 CPU ARMv7.I am trying to use  ARM Streamline but it provides the following error:

ARM Processor PMU event counters have been detected, however the event counters are reading zeroes. Event counters include those counters listed in the counter configuration options dialog under the core name but exclude the cycle counter (Clock:Cycles) as it is controlled by a dedicated counter. It is possible that the PMU configuration bit DBGEN has not been enabled, and counter values subsequently will always read as zero. To remedy, please update your firmware or Linux kernel to enable DBGEN.

after some search i found similar problem: https://community.freescale.com/thread/302685

which suggest some modification to the SDER Secure Debug Enable Register, Security Extensions.

i do not know what to so i found a file perf_event in kernel source but not sure where to start.

i found out here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0195b/DAI0195B_arm11_performance_monitor_unit.pdf for ARM11 that   i should use

```
enter code here

// MRC p15, 0, <Rd>, CRn, CRm, opCode_2 ; base

MRC p15, 0, <Rd>, c15, c12, 0 ; Read Performance Monitor Control Register

MCR p15, 0, <Rd>, c15, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register
```

this is in perf_event_v6.c kernel folder like this:

```
static inline unsigned long
armv6_pmcr_read(void)
{
    u32 val;
    asm volatile("mrc   p15, 0, %0, c15, c12, 0" : "=r"(val));
    return val;
}
```

since i'm using version arm7 so i should modify perf_event_v7.c
and my guessing that i should use c9 instead of c15 because this is the option used there and mentioned in the Cortex Reference manual for EX:

c9 registers
Table 4-10 shows the CP15 system control registers you can access when CRn is c9.
Table 4-10 c9 register summary
Op1 CRm Op2 Name       Type Reset      Description
0   c12 0   PMCR       RW   0x41093000 Performance Monitor Control Register
        1   PMCNTENSET RW   0x00000000 Count Enable Set Register
        2   PMCNTENCLR RW   0x00000000 Count Enable Clear Register
        3   PMOVSR     RW        -     Overflow Flag Status Register
        4   PMSWINC    WO        -     Software Increment Register
        5   PMSELR     RW   0x00000000 Event Counter Selection Register

so it should be :
    MRC p15, 0, , c9, c12, 0 ; Read Performance Monitor Control Register

```
MCR p15, 0, <Rd>, c9, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register
```

and
    MRC p15, 0, , c9, c12, 5 ; Read PMSELR Register

```
MCR p15, 0, <Rd>, c9, c12, 5 ; Write PMSELR Register
```

and to choose the event:

```
  EXPORT  pmn_config
  ; Sets the event for a programmable counter to record
  ; void pmn_config(unsigned counter, uint32_t event)
  ; counter (in r0) = Which counter to program (e.g. 0 for PMN0, 1 for PMN1)
  ; event   (in r1) = The event code (from appropriate TRM or ARM Architecture  Reference Manual)
  pmn_config PROC
  AND     r0, r0, #0x1F          ; Mask to leave only bits 4:0
  MCR     p15, 0, r0, c9, c12, 5 ; Write PMSELR Register
  ISB                            ; Synchronize context
  MCR     p15, 0, r1, c9, c13, 1 ; Write PMXEVTYPER Register
  BX      lr
  ENDP
```

the steps i should follow are as follow:
The following procedure should be followed:

```
Disable performance counters
Set what each event counter will count
Set cycle counter tick rate
Reset performance counters
Enable performance counters
Call function to profile
Disable performance counters
Read out performance counters
Check that performance counters did not overflow
```

but i still did not know how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might help you ->
https://code.google.com/p/mycodespot/wiki/DirectPMUCodeGCC

This link has PMU header and assembly code and an application example to how to use the code and compile.